# Powershell script to remove tempory files and registry keys

Tags: powershell, removechild, system-variable

I've created a small PowerShell script to remove a Autodesk application.  However, PowerShell doesn't seam to like system variables like %username%.  Whats the best way of achieving this in Powershell?

```
 # Remove all Autodesk products from a Windows System 
 $AutoDeskPaths = "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk", "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Autodesk", "C:\ProgramData\Autodesk", "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2012", "C:\Program Files\AutoCAD 2010", "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared","HKCU:Software\Autodesk", "HKLU:Software\Autodesk"
 Remove-item $AutoDeskPaths -Recurse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access environment variables like this:

```
$Env:UserName
```

Comment: Just so the rest of you know.  This is the final script i used.

     # Remove all Autodesk products from a Windows System 
     $AutoDeskPaths = "C:\Users\$Env:UserName\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk",      "C:\Users\$Env:UserName\AppData\Local\Autodesk", "C:\ProgramData\Autodesk", "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2012", "C:\Program Files\AutoCAD 2010", "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared","HKCU:Software\Autodesk", "HKLU:Software\Autodesk"
     Remove-item $AutoDeskPaths -Recurse